# JavaScript Moment.js trying to get the difference between 2 datetimes

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs, ticker

I am trying to get the difference between 2 datetimestamps which look like These:

```
2018-08-22 00:00:00 
2018-08-11 15:34:31
```

I want to Show the difference in time in days - Hours - minutes - seconds left.

So far I did this but it Always return NaN:

```
import moment from 'moment';

const calc = {

    render () {
        moment().format();
        this.calcDifference();
    },

    calcDifference() {
        let releaseDate = document.getElementById('release-at').value;
        let currentDate = document.getElementById('current-date').value;

        let ms = moment(
            releaseDate,
            "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(currentDate,
            "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss")
        );
        let d = moment.duration(ms);
        let s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");

        console.log(ms);
        console.log(d);
        console.log(s);
    }

};

    calc.render();
```

Comment: Moment can give difference only if it is less than 24hrs. You need to write your own calculation

Comment: Your timestamps don't match the format you're trying to parse to.

Comment: @H77 yes true MS Returns this 347094234000 and s Returns this 96415:03:54 how would you proceed ?

Comment: @tigerel is it working?  I could not reproduce the error : [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yd4a3ugq/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your `calcDifference` function, you can do something like this

```
let releaseDate = moment('2018-09-22 00:00:00');
let currentDate = moment('2018-08-11 15:34:31');

const diff = releaseDate.diff(currentDate);
const diffDuration = moment.duration(diff);

console.log(`
  ${diffDuration.months()} months
  ${diffDuration.days()} days
  ${diffDuration.hours()} hours
  ${diffDuration.minutes()} minutes
  ${diffDuration.seconds()} seconds left!`);
```

in case values from **release-at** and **current-date** elements have format 
`DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss`, use

```
let releaseDate = moment(document.getElementById('release-at').value, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss');
let currentDate = moment(document.getElementById('current-date').value, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss');
```

Here's a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/codepen-theo/pen/bjzMQQ?editors=0010)

I hope it helps! :)

Comment: Awesome this worked perfectly, how would you make a ticker so to say which Counts down the seconds then the minutes and so on?

Comment: @tigerel of course! i don't like to spoil you that much but i have energy today :) give me a moment

Comment: @tigerel—there are [*many questions*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+countdown+timer) here already on countdown timers, if you have an issue that isn't covered there, ask another question.

Comment: @Theo—please don't answer questions in comments with code on another site. New questions should be asked as new questions. There are plenty of questions here already on timers and countdowns that cover issues not addressed in your code.